# How to load and store nvarchar

Tags: hadoop, character-encoding, hive, sqoop, nvarchar

​Stack : Installed HDP-2.3.2.0-2950 using Ambari 2.1
The steps that I am following :
​

1. Load SQL server tables onto HDFS using Sqoop
2. Create EXTERNAL tables in Hive

I didn't use anything pertaining to charset/unicode/utf-8 while executing the sqoop import commands and the import was successful

While creating the Hive external table, I was wondering what data type shall I select for the nvarchar columns in the original sql server table, now I am worried that even in Sqoop while importing that needs to be addressed.

1. ​Couldn't find relevant charset/nvarchar etc. options in Sqoop import
2. In Hive, can varchar/string blindly be used in place of nvarchar

Comment: Hadoop and Hive natively use **UTF-8** therefore they don't need to care about the legacy issues about legacy charsets. If the charset definitions are OK for all columns in SQL Server, and if the Microsoft JDBC driver does its job of converting source charsets to Java client charset, then you are done.

Comment: I have proceeded with the varchar Hive data type instead of String, I hope that doesn't cause any issues. The Sqoop import didn't give any errors.

Comment: In Hive, VARCHAR == (STRING + check on Write that actual length complies with max length) so the difference is cosmetic.

Comment: Some inputs found here :

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/31499/how-to-load-and-store-nvarchar.html#answer-32426

Answer (score 0):

We know that `nvarchar` type is not understandable by `sqoop` then we need to just cast it as `varchar`
e.g.

```
select 
CAST(col1 AS varchar )  AS col1,
col2,
col3,
col4
from table_name
```