# Import to HDFS or Hive(directly)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

1. Stack : Installed HDP-2.3.2.0-2950 using Ambari 2.1
2. The source is a MS SQL database of around 1.6TB and around 25 tables
   The ultimate objective is to check if the existing queries can run faster on the HDP
3. There isn't a luxury of time and availability to import the data several times, hence, the import has to be done once and the Hive tables, queries etc. need to be experimented with, for example, first create a normal, partitioned table in ORC. If it doesn't suffice, try indexes and so on. Possibly, we will also evaluate the Parquet format and so on

4.As a solution to 4., I decided to first import the tables onto HDFS in Avro format for example :

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://server;database=dbname' --username someuser --password somepassword --as-avrodatafile --num-mappers 8 --table tablename --warehouse-dir /dataload/tohdfs/ --verbose
```

Now I plan to create a Hive table but I have some questions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033391/how-to-load-and-store-nvarchar).

My question is that given all the points above, what is the safest(in terms of time and NOT messing the HDFS etc.) approach - to first bring onto HDFS, create Hive tables and experiment or directly import in Hive(I dunno if now I delete these tables and wish to start afresh, do I have to re-import the data)

Comment: I see a contradiction between these 2 assertions: *"no time to import data several times"* vs *"target tables must be experimented ... recreating tables w/ different options"*. If you want to try different SerDe (ORC, Parquet) with different partitioning schemes, then you have to re-create the Hive tables and reload them several times.

Comment: So **what do you mean** by "importing data" -- you want to create a dump in portable format (e.g. CSV) in HDFS, to be used as a source many times? Use `Sqoop`. Or you want an end-to-end solution to read from SQL Server and load data directly to your partitioned ORC / Parquet format? Use `Spark`, the latest version can do parallel load just like Sqoop *(but beware about some options that are not taken automatically from the Metastore, such as Parquet compression -- and partition management is not straightforward)*

Comment: By 'importing data', I mean 'access the sql server and load data onto hdfs' i.e I can do whatever I wish to in Hive any no. of times but I cannot access the sql server more than once to fetch the data.
I have imported sql server tables in Avro format and now I am building Hive ORC and Hive Avro tables atop, the only confusion that remains is whether Avro file format during import will pose perf. issues later when Hive queries are executed

Comment: With ORC don't forget that you can tweak some properties, depending on data profile & query patterns -- cf. http://fr.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/hanson-o-malleypandeyjune27425pmroom212/16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Loading, you can try these options

1) You can do a mysql import to csv file that will be stored in your Linux file system as backup then do a distcp to HDFS.

2) As mentioned, you can do a Sqoop import and load the data to Hive table (parent_table).

For checking the performance using different formats & Partition table, you can use CTAS (Create Table As Select) queries, where you can create new tables from the base table (parent_table). In CTAS, you can mention the format like parque or avro etc and partition options is also there.

Even if you delete new tables created by CTAS, the base table will be there.

Based on my experience, Parque + partition will give a best performance, but it also depends on your data.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the connection and settings are all correct. But I dint see `--fetch-size` in the query. By default the `--fetch-size` is 1000 which would take forever in your case. If the no of columns are less. I would recommend increasing the `--fetch-size 10000`. I have gone up to 50000 when the no of columns are less than 50. Maybe 20000 if you have 100 columns. I would recommend checking the size of data per row and then decide. If there is one column which has size greater than 1MB data in it. Then I would not recommend anything above 1000.